# Handling a null header value

Tags: python, django

I'm passing a header value to a list endpoint to only get objects after a certain date, this works all fine until the front end pass null as the value.

My code for this looks like this;

```
        updated = self.request.headers.get("Updated", None)
        type(updated)
        if updated is None or updated is "null":
            ....
        else:
          ....
```

If the header value passed is `Updated: null` this crashes, I've tried comparing to both None and the text null but I still get the error;

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“null” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

As it's falling into the else category, `type(updated)` prints out `null` in the terminal but I can't find anywhere where to compare updated to a null value, according to what I've found this should be covered by None. I could fix this on my FE but I feel like this would leave the BE open to a 500 error for no reason.

Comment: Change `is` to `==`, so `update == "null"`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's fixed it, is using `is` a comparison of type over value? If you post that as the answer I can accept it. Silly mistakes like this, ahh!

Comment: "_I'm passing a header value to a list endpoint to only get objects after a certain date_" Why pass this in the request headers? pass it as a GET parameter or a POST parameter or whatever kind of request you make.

Comment: @Dannys `is` checks if the variable refers to the same object in the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do *not* use `is`, unless you are sure that you need this. `is` checks if two expressions refer to the *same* object. But two strings can contain both `'null'`, but still can be different objects.

Therefore you thus perform string comparisons with:

```
if updated is None or updated == 'null':
    # …
```